# Issue Finding Substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dataframe

I'm trying to find a substring **Chief** in the df column. Its working fine with `split()` on text with spaces but not working as expected with `find()`.

```
sum(df['JobTitle'].apply(lambda x :'chief' in x.lower().split() ))
sum(df['JobTitle'].apply(lambda x :  x.lower().find('chief') ==1))
```

Can you please highlight what the issue in `find` usage is here?

Comment: .find returns the index, not whether or not it's in the string.

Comment: Understood rassar. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `re`:

```py
import re

# if it appears, add 1, else add 0
sum(df['JobTitle'].apply(lambda x : int(bool(re.findall(r'\bchief\b', x.lower()))))

# add the number of times the word appears
sum(df['JobTitle'].apply(lambda x : len(re.findall(r'\bchief\b', x.lower())))
```

**EDIT** 
If you want to catch `chief` but not words with chief inside, like `mischief`, use `r'\bchief\b'`

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/jYOfM1/1

Comment: Giving Error :

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-ce0cfde9f982> in <module>
      3 
      4 import re
----> 5 sum(df['JobTitle'].apply(lambda x : re.findall(r'chief', x.lower())))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: ```sum(df['JobTitle'].apply(lambda x : 0 if re.search(r'chief', x.lower()) is None else 1)
```

above 1 is working fine but i need to understand what i'm missing in normal find method ?

Comment: Thanks sashaboulouds ,  I tried  with below but the problem with re is its counting additional words where the individual word is not chief but contains chief like chieftain ,mischief etc


```sum(df['JobTitle'].apply(lambda x : 0 if len(re.findall(r'chief', x.lower()))==0 else 1))```

Comment: Just `edited` my answer, if solved, please notify it as solved

Comment: i did, but seems since my reputation is low it wont add up